# How to send post request that takes byte array from Angular to Web Api?

Tags: angular

My Web Api desire byte[] in post request.

In my Angular 2 application I have file input, which I want to send as byte array.

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" name="image">

onChange(event){
this.file=event.target.files[0];
```

I send the file through post request, but in Web Api I'm getting null instead of that object, which is typicall when it's not the desired type.

I also tried sending form data with the same result.

```
var payload = new FormData();
payload.append("name", file);
```

Any idea if is it possible to send byte[] in angular via post request?